# Windows 10 LTSB USB drivers do not save after power off

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers

I've recently switched over from Windows 10 Pro down to Windows 10 LTSB and I'm having issues where my USB devices do not retain their drivers and settings after I shutdown the PC and use it again the next day.

By retaining drivers, I specifically mean that if I re-plug in a device (webcam, game controller, USB hard drive), Windows 10 LTSB will have to reinstall the driver for that device, even though the driver was installed the last time the device was plugged in. As a result, any custom settings I had set for these devices are lost, and I have to reset them each time.

It's quite an odd problem, and I haven't seen anyone really have this issue before. To reiterate, I did not have this problem back in Windows 10 Pro either.

Has anyone ever seen this happen? Is there a potential solution or setting in LTSB that I'm unaware of to let USB drivers persist after the device has been disconnected?

EDIT: For further reference, I found that Windows is deleting the drivers explicitly for whatever reason. See this screenshot:

[image: http://puu.sh/zA9h0/ba75e7779c.png]

Comment: LTSB is a special version for critical devices (POS, ATM) but nor for your gaming. I doubt you get it legally, so no support here. Go back to Pro

Comment: I have a legitimate copy of LTSB. I realize that this version is not for gaming but I appreciate the fact that it's much more lightweight than Pro. I was hoping there was some sort of setting that I may have missed but if there are no other options then I will revert back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this and it worked well!

https://support.microsoft.com/cs-cz/help/4098563/usb-device-drivers-are-removed-unexpectedly-after-windows-update-windo

Comment: Link only answer is useless, especially when it will be broken.
Can you elaborate on this a little more?

Comment: Link works for me. It seems like a good solution but I ended up reverting back to Windows 10 Pro because I couldn't find a solution to this problem :(